# Backup to iSCSI drive stalls when I attempt to utilize multipath

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012

Simple question; I Have a storage filer attached to my network, with two links connected to it, under the same virtual interface/IP address. This is connected to one of our servers through iSCSI, and works well *most* of the time, However if I enable Multi-path on the target interface, no matter how I configure the initiator, about 10GB into an operation on Windows Server Backup, the operation stalls backing up, and I have to manually cancel it.

I never encounter this without Multipathing on the storage Filer enabled, and such backup operations work, while much slower. I can cope with this, but does anyone know why it occurs and how I can fix it? Thanks.

Filer in question is a NetApp FAS2020 with Data ONTAP 7.3, and Windows Server edition 2012 R2.

Comment: You are missing your switch info/config, as for me it can easilly be a switch trouble.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how its configured in this area, really as far as I know the target and initiator are just on the same subnet, both on the same switch.

Comment: In multipathing the switch with spanning-tree config detect a link broke and balance over the other link. Thats how I'am used to do it, maybe other config exit, but as you see it's to be sure if a path fall dead, that the link don't drop. (in your case with only one switch you have a single point of failure there)